# Detect a record that triggers a change in the incremental numbering in an array

Tags: php, mysql, increment

I have a set of records and each one gets a number

```
NAME    | NUMBER
Record1 | 1
Record2 | 2
Record3 | 3
Record4 | 4
Record5 | 5
Record6 | 6
Record8 | 7
```

The table can be updated and a possible version is presented below

```
NAME     | NUMBER
Record1  | 1
Record2  | 2
Record4  | 3
Record5  | 4
Record6  | 5
Record7  | 6
Record10 | 7
```

Each time a record is added before an existing one the numbering is changing for all the records after the new one. If one record is added the numbering will increase by 1, if two records are added the numbering will increase by 2 and so on. Also after an update the table can have less rows than before.

Each row is added and removed in the table when certain conditions are met, for example when its status flag changes.

I am not able to know the ordering of the records before they are added in the specific table, nor when they will be added, in order to assign a unique number from the very start.

I am comparing the tables before and after the changes to detect any changes and the result returned is all the rows that have a new numbering but the row that triggered the changes is not returned.

```
$a = array_diff($tableBefore, $tableAfter);
$b = array_diff($tableAfter, $tableBefore);

$differences = array_merge(array_diff($a, $b), array_diff($b, $a));
```

I need to detect the single record or the set of records that triggered a change in the incremental numbering.

How can I achieve that without resolving to `foreach` loops and checking each new and old record if it's there or not and/or if it has a new number ?

Comment: Load the data into an associative array, and use `array_diff_assoc` to compare them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the table data into associative arrays, e.g.

```
$tableBefore = array(
    'Record1' => 1,
    'Record2' => 2,
    ...
    'Record8' => 7
);
$tableAfter = array(
    'Record1' => 1,
    'Record2' => 2,
    ...
    'Record10' => 7
);
```

Then use

```
$differences = array_merge(array_diff_assoc($tableBefore, $tableAfter),
                           array_diff_assoc($tableAfter, $tableBefore));
```

Comment: It worked! The returning results are what I expected to see. 

I thought an associative array wouldn't be the solution to this.